# Delaying the pdf generation when using ExpertPdf converter

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am using [ExpertPdf](http://www.expertpdf.net) html to pdf converter to convert a web page to pdf. It works fine with most pages, but when I try to convert a page with HighCharts javascript charts on it, only part of the charts are rendered.

My guess is that rendering those charts take longer. Is there a way to delay the pdf generation and allow the full page to load?

Comment: I don;t about delaying anything, but this seems to work great ... http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.SVGCharts.HighCharts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the ConversionDelay property of the PdfConverter object to a few seconds. Also make sure that javascript is enabled.

```
PdfConverter converter = new PdfConverter();
converter.ConversionDelay = 2;
converter.ScriptsEnabled = true;
byte[] pdf = converter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(url);
```

You can find support resources for ExpertPdf here:
http://www.html-to-pdf.net/Support.aspx